# VBA Selenium - Can't click on button nor press escape to hide it

Tags: vba, selenium

I just discovered Selenium exists and in my first test (unfortunately) performed it in this page:

http://www.cedulaprofesional.sep.gob.mx/cedula/indexAvanzada.action

i am trying to hide the first dialog clicking on the "x" or pressing escape but:

- escape doesn't do the trick
- using getbyid, class name or css says it is hidden and cannot interact with it.

can someone please help me?

Thanks in advance for your time and attention,

````

Sub getDataFromSEP()
    Dim driver As New SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver

```
driver.Start "firefox"
driver.maximizeWindow

driver.setTimeout (120000)
driver.setImplicitWait (1000)
driver.Open "http://www.cedulaprofesional.sep.gob.mx/cedula/indexAvanzada.action"
driver.waitForPageToLoad (360000)
driver.Wait 3000

driver.windowFocus

driver.findElementByCssSelector("span.dijitDialogCloseIcon.dijitDialogCloseIconHover").Click
driver.findElementById("condiciones").Click
driver.findElementByLinkText("Búsqueda por Cédula").Click
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe it is too late but there is an answer.

Using Selenium IDE

```
driver.click "css=span.dijitDialogCloseIcon.dijitDialogCloseIconHover"
```

Comment: Please improve your question